# Unsure how to unmount scene in @react/three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-router, react-three-fiber

I'm building this scene, and I have a few issues.

One small issue is with `directionalLight`.  When I try using more up to date three.js attributes like `shadow.camera.far` on it, @react-three/fiber loses the ability to call the dispose function on the light's shadows.  So, I have to use the deprecated properties, which causes me to get these annoying warnings.  That's not the biggest problem though.  I can live with that, but I'd also be grateful if anyone had any idea how to get rid of those warnings.

The main problem is that when I try making the model in my scene clickable so that the user can go to a different page in the app, I get a @react-three/fiber error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disconnect' of undefined`.  I think this is because I'm using the `unmountComponentAtNode` function in the scene's useEffect hook, and it's causing the component to unmount before @react-three/fiber can properly remove all the threejs objects.  However, when I remove that function, I get the common react error of: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function`.

Anyone have any idea what I can do?  I'd appreciate any help.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  Canvas,
  extend,
  unmountComponentAtNode,
  useFrame,
  useLoader,
  useThree,
} from '@react-three/fiber'
import { CubeTextureLoader, DoubleSide, PerspectiveCamera, sRGBEncoding } from 'three'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import Model3D from '../../assets/models/model.glb'
import './Model.css'
import nx from '../../assets/environmentMap/nx.jpg'
import ny from '../../assets/environmentMap/ny.jpg'
import nz from '../../assets/environmentMap/nz.jpg'
import px from '../../assets/environmentMap/px.jpg'
import py from '../../assets/environmentMap/py.jpg'
import pz from '../../assets/environmentMap/pz.jpg'

extend({ OrbitControls })

const wallMap = {
  'side-panel': '/wall/1',
  'panel-material': '/wall/2',
  'panel-material-2': '/wall/3',
  'side-panel-2': '/wall/4',
  entrance: '/wall/5',
  'overhead-entrance': '/wall/5',
}

const CameraControls = () => {
  const {
    camera,
    gl: { domElement },
  } = useThree()

  const controls = useRef()
  useFrame(() => controls.current.update())

  return <orbitControls ref={controls} args={[camera, domElement]} enableDamping />
}

const SkyBox = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  const loader = new CubeTextureLoader()
  const environmentMap = loader.load([px, nx, py, ny, pz, nz])

  environmentMap.encoding = sRGBEncoding
  scene.background = environmentMap
  scene.environment = environmentMap

  return null
}

const Model = ({ changePage }) => {
  const active = useRef(false)
  const moving = useRef(false)

  const material = useRef()
  const { scene } = useThree()
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, Model3D)
  const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)
  camera.position.set(-4.62, 1.3, 4)
  scene.add(camera)

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (moving.current) return

    const {
      material: { name },
    } = e.intersections[0].object

    changePage(wallMap[name])
  }

  const handlePointerDown = () => {
    active.current = true
  }

  const handlePointerUp = () => {
    if (active.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        moving.current = false
        active.current = false
      }, 30)
    }
  }

  const handlePointerMove = () => {
    if (active.current) {
      moving.current = true
    }
  }

  return (
    <primitive
      object={gltf.scene}
      position={[0, -1.25, 0]}
      scale={0.22}
      rotation={[0, -0.6, 0]}
      castShadow
      onClick={handleClick}
      onPointerDown={handlePointerDown}
      onPointerMove={handlePointerMove}
      onPointerUp={handlePointerUp}
    >
      <meshStandardMaterial attach='material' ref={material} />
    </primitive>
  )
}

const Plane = () => {
  return (
    <mesh receiveShadow rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, -0.8, 0]}>
      <planeGeometry args={[12.5, 12.5, 2, 2]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color='#222' side={DoubleSide} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

const Scene = () => {
  const [redirectPath, setRedirectPath] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (redirectPath) window.appHistory.push(redirectPath)

    return () => {
      unmountComponentAtNode(document.querySelector('canvas'))
    }
  }, [redirectPath])

  return (
    <div className='webgl'>
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <ambientLight color='#ffffff' intensity={0.3} />
          <directionalLight
            position={[-3, 5, 5]}
            color='#ffffff'
            intensity={3}
            castShadow
            // Last 4 are deprecated properties that cause warnings from three.js.
            // When I use something like shadow={ { bias: 0.05 } }, I lose the dispose
            // function from the shadow.  So, I'm still using them for now.
            shadowBias={0.05}
            shadowCameraFar={15}
            shadowMapHeight={1024}
            shadowMapWidth={1024}
          />
          <CameraControls />
          <Model changePage={(x) => setRedirectPath(x)} />
          <Plane />
          <SkyBox />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Scene
```

Comment: unmountcomponentatnode is only for when you use the render api https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/render-function calling that while using the canvas root component essentially pulls the carpet from underneath it. if canvas simply unmounts it will clean up and dispose of all data.

Comment: I see.  That's what I thought as well, but the thing is, if I don't add it, I get this problem that my component has a memory leak.  What would be the proper way to take care of that in my case?

Comment: best would be to make that into a small codesandbox and create a GH issue. if this is a leak it needs to get fixed.